# A good site to learn Anki for chess openings?

Tags: opening

Can someone tell me a good website in order to learn to use Anki for chess opening improvement?

Comment: Hi Andy, welcome to Chess Stack Exchange! I'm not aware of the type of site you are looking for, but I suggest that you look at [this question](http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/8100/effectiveness-of-a-spaced-repetition-system-srs-for-memorizing-tactical-patter) and follow the links there.

Answer (score 2):

[Anki](http://ankisrs.net) is a program for [spaced repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaced_repetition). You can use it [to train chess](https://ankiweb.net/shared/decks/Chess) without being online at all.

[Chesstempo](http://chesstempo.com) is a site on which you can train chess and it also allows you to use [spaced repetition](http://chesstempo.com/user-guide/en/probSearchSpacedRepetition.html).