# Anki deck for tactics training

Tags: tactics, training

Does anybody have Anki decks for tactics training? If anyone has such decks, could you share them with me?

I am trying to improve my tactics and I have heard that space repetition is one way to do that. As such I want to have some decks to give it a shot. I've been searching for chess tactics decks, but I can't find any.

Comment: Although there are no pointers to existing Anki decks, you may also be interested in the question [Effectiveness of a spaced repetition system (SRS) for memorizing tactical patterns for long-term skill gain?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/8100/10867).

Comment: Though it is not answering the question, but rather the underlying problem, there are many websites and apps which provide that functionality with adaptive training options (i.e. it gives you puzzles according to your current level). Nevertheless, if you ever reach a satisfying solution with Anki, let us know and if possible share your deck with the community as an example and encouragement for others.

Answer (score 5):

Truth is there isn't a lot out there for chess. The best I could find was this from the Ankiweb site - https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1176122148 There aren't many free decks for chess but it does guide you into how to make your own which you can do using puzzles that you find and like in books and the web.

For getting started with Anki Alex Vermeer's site has some useful stuff - https://alexvermeer.com/anki-essentials/

Answer (score 3):

You can easily craft your own anki decks based on pgn files. You just need to craft a .csv file that has on the first column the FEN positions as [fen]setup[/fen] and on the second column the solution. If you import the csv in Anki, you'll end up with cards that have the board set up in one side and the annotation on the other side.

I wrote a guide on how to manipulate pgn to craft csv files can be found here:
https://jpr.space/posts/linux-anki-chess/

Comment: Welcome to Chess Stack Exchange! Is that your own post you're linking to? If so, you need to indicate that in your answer, see the [Help Center](/help/promotion).

Answer (score 2):

I made a template here
https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/1082754005

and some tactics https://ankiweb.net/shared/info/2047046995

Comment: Welcome to Chess! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

A quite inexpensive app iChess will allow displaying & solving a collection of puzzles on Android phones & tablets. As with Anki you put the puzzle in a pgn file with tag lines [Setup "1"] & [FEN "..."]. The author supplies a few files but it will read your own. I've collected about 800 puzzles in my own files.

Answer (score 0):

Lichess.org is a great source for tactics collections which can be exported to PGN (portable game notation) file. I have built an online [tool](https://www.chessflashcards.com/create/tactics/) that automatically converts tactics saved in a PGN file to Anki flashcards deck.

Please check out my [video](https://youtu.be/6Z0n-AKxNCg) for instructions on how to build Anki deck for tactics training automatically out of PGN file. It provides instructions on how to convert tactics found on Lichess.org website to Anki flashcards deck.